# How to make gradient border work on mobile phones too?

Tags: gradient, css

I have this code:

```
#likebuttonsmob {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 340px; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 23px; padding-top: 4px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px;
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(119, 119, 119, 0)) 1 1 1 1;
border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(119, 119, 119, 0)) 1 1 1 1;
border-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(119, 119, 119, 0)) 1 1 1 1;
border-image: -o-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(119, 119, 119, 0)) 1 1 1 1;
}
```

for making a gradient border on top and bottom of some social buttons if the page is lower that 1090px (I'm interested more for mobile phones). With the code above, everything is working as it should on my PC if I resize the window, but on my mobile phone, the top and bottom borders are solid and I can't see the gradient. Can somebody help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Example page: http://www.cumseface.eu/viewtopic.php?t=279

Comment: Pretty hard to work out what buttons you are referring to.

Comment: The facebook like button, google + and tweet . The ones that are above the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of mobile versions don't necessarily support gradient, dependent on their version of course, check here first:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/images/gradients_mobile.html

And then for using specific mobile browsing compatibility you can use media queries.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp